How to connect Linux to a WPA2-EAP-CCMP Wi-Fi network?
Summary: after having gone through tons of documentation pages, I still cannot connect my Debian to a WPA2-EAP-CCMP Wi-Fi
The NIC is correctly configured (driver-wise):
# iwconfig

wlx00e04c45ad46  unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

(wpa_cli > scan)

78:f1:c6:bd:e7:89       5260    -53     [WPA2-EAP-CCMP][ESS]    the_SSID_of_the_network

The wired network is set up via /etc/network/interfaces, so I added there
auto wlx00e04c45ad46
iface wlx00e04c45ad46 inet dhcp
wpa-key_mgmt "WPA-EAP"
wpa-pairwise "CCMP"
wpa-ssid "the_SSID_of_the_network"
wpa-identity "my_login"
wpa-password "my_password"

The network is always in the unassociated state, and DOWN
# ip a

6: wlx00e04c45ad46: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:e0:4c:45:ad:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Note: this network requires a login and a password to connect (not a PSK)

Has wpa_supplicant said anything about this in your system logs? It's usually very verbose when anything goes wrong during the EAP handshake.

@grawity_u1686 oh sorry, I forgot to mention that: journalctl -f does not show anything related

Is it even running then? What happens when you ifup -v the interface? (Though I would personally much rather configure this either within wpa_supplicant directly, or through NetworkManager – I don't trust Debian's ifupdown all that much.)

@grawity_u1686 ifup: interface wlx00e04c45ad46 already configured. TBH networking on Debian is a nightmare (having used Linux since 1994). There seems to be a zillion ways (3 I think) to do that. I am open to any suggestions and I will go form there.

@grawity_u1686 I will give it a try to NetworkManager, an opportunity to learn something new

@grawity_u1686 well, I managed to connect with NetworkManager :) I had to guess settings (and merge form various forums) but at least it is there. THANK YOU! Could you please bootstrap an answer ("use NetworkManager" :)) and I will update it to give you all credit/rep
